# MongoDB 3.2 - authenticate from localhost

Tags: mongodb

Just upgraded from Debian8 to Debian9. My MongoDB instance was upgraded as well (2.4 -> 3.2). Authentication is enabled. 
In 2.4 when logging from localhost you could simply connect via mongo and was granted administrative privileges:

```
mongo
```

After doing some research it seems to me that in 3.2 you MUST login via some user/password combination even from localhost. But that seems awfully inconvenient.

```
mongo localhost/admin -u superAdminUser -p
```

So my question is whether that is really true and you do need to always use user/password combination? Or maybe I missed something and logging as superuser from localhost is still possible with no user/password?

Answer (score 0):

if you start Mongodb by the following command , you will need to insert user name and password

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --auth &
```

also check /etc/mongod.conf file , you can enable/disable authentication .

```
security.authorization : enabled
```

As I know there is no way to disable authentication on local host only .
you can disable/enable authentication for all hosts which want to connect to Database

Comment: In both cases (Debian8, Debian9) Mongo is started with regular system init.d script (no customization here). In both cases a configuration is used that enables authentication:

    # Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
    #noauth = true
    auth = true

And with such configuration, MongoDB 2.4 on Debian8 allows superuser login from localhost with no credentials. Mongo 3.2 on D9 does not.

Comment: @randomUsername MongoDB in default mode does not use athentication

Comment: you can stop mongodb and start it by the mentiond command  -->>    mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --auth &

Comment: I had the same problem , Don't  trust on config file , maybe there is a syntax problem .

Comment: also use  -->> mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --noauth &  to disable authentication

Comment: That does not give me anything. As I said before: Debian8 + Mongo 2.4 ---> can login as superuser from localhost with no credentials required, credentials are still required when logging in from external networks. Debian9 + Mongo 3.2 on the exact same configuration ---> credentials are required for login attempts both from localhost and external networks. So why the difference?